# Dropkick.js - change height of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript

I have installed Dropkick to be able to create nice looking dropdowns [http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/]

My test is installed here:
http://test.mobilkul.se/dropkick/

Width is calculated in regards to the longest element in the dropdown menu.

I would like to increase the height of this dropdown.

Right now 8 options are showed if I click on the button.

Is this possible or is this a browser issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at dropkick's CSS file, you'll find the following at line `132` - *Check it out using Firebug or Chrome dev inspector*.

```
.dk_options_inner, .dk_touch .dk_options {
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

You can either:

Change that `250px` to whatever you need - for example, `350px`

*OR*

Override the style in your CSS file (recommended):

```
body .dk_options_inner, .dk_touch .dk_options { /* see body prefix for more specificity */
    max-height: 350px;
}
```